# htaccess Rewrite Rules issu

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, htaccess

I am struggling with my RewriteRules. I want to handle requests as follows:

Requests that match example.com/15 (domain/any number), should be handled by my cdn. So I wrote this, but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ../../cdn.example.com/public_html/l/i.php?id=$1
```

My server replies with 400 Bad Request and nothing more.

The following worked for me on an older xampp installation.

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ ./e/$1.php
```

(Now I am using linux apache2.) I tried to solve the problem by using [Jon Lin's script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572613/htaccess-rewriterule), but this gives me 400 or 404.

My WebApp should be doing this:
- Loading contents using my lite-cdn to the main page and manipulating the url to look like a link was clicked. 
 -When you reload the page (F5), the first htaccess rule should apply.

Comment: I discovered that my htacces rule is fine, but the path (../../cdn.example.com/public_html/l/i.php) is not ok

I configured the index.php in example.com to answer these requests and it worked. But the rule won't let me use the cdn-php-file..

Comment: One solution might be to redirect the requests to a file in the example.com dir, which uses the content files from the cdn via the local file system